# Print PHP Shuffled Array To An Ordered List

Tags: php, html-lists

I want to shuffle an array once a week and print it in an order list like this. So once a week this order would be different. I have the code for the array shuffle below, but having trouble printing the array to the ordered list - was going to figure out how to fire the script once a week after I got this part figured out.

1. Northland
2. North Linden
3. South Linden
4. Brice-Tussing
5. Greater Hilltop
6. Southside

Here is the php code for the array shuffle:

```
<?php
$area_list = array(1 => "Northland", 2 => "North Linden", 3 => "South Linden", 4 => "Brice-Tussing", 5 => "Greater Hilltop", 6 => "Southside");
shuffle($area_list);
print_r($area_list); 
?>
```

And this is my (bloated) code for the ordered list (ol):

```
<ol>
    <li> 
      <div align="left"> 
        <div align="left"><font color="#333333"><font size="2" >Northland</font></font></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <div align="left"> 
        <div align="left"><font color="#333333"><font size="2" > North Linden</font></font></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <div align="left"> 
        <div align="left"><font color="#333333"><font size="2" > South Linden</font></font></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <div align="left"> 
        <div align="left"><font color="#333333"><font size="2" > Brice-Tussing</font></font></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li> 
      <div align="left"> 
        <div align="left"><font color="#333333"><font size="2" > Greater Hilltop</font></font></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div align="left">
        <div align="left"><font color="#333333"><font size="2" > Southside 
          </font></font></div>
      </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Columbus Ohio neighborhoods in case you were wondering. Thanks.

Comment: He means it will be output in an HTML <ol> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `foreach`:

```
<?php
$area_list = array(1 => "Northland", 2 => "North Linden", 3 => "South Linden", 4 => "Brice-Tussing", 5 => "Greater Hilltop", 6 => "Southside");
shuffle($area_list);
echo "<ol>";
foreach($area_list as $area){
    echo '<li><div align="left"><div align="left"><font color="#333333"><font size="2" >'.$area.'</font></font></div></div></li>';
}
echo "</ol>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is output your starting tags (for the OL), and then loop through the $area_list array:

```
<ol><?php foreach ($area_list as $al) {

?><li> 
  <div align="left"> 
    <div align="left"><font color="#333333"><font size="2" ><?php echo $al;
?></font></font></div>
      </div>
    </li>
<?php 
}
```

After that, output your closing "" and you should have what you want, or close to it.  Post back if you have further questions/problems.

Comment: Incidentally, you're using some fairly antiquated tags there ... consider using something else besides "<font>" tags (maybe some CSS?) ....

Comment: Thank you both for such a fast response. I’ll get back on here and let you know if I succeed. @Kevin yeah....it’s old HTML 4 // I’m building a static site (sick of bloated CMS - WP etc) for load speed priority and I’m not using CSS or JS - so far 99/100 tests on Google Insights

Comment: I kind of get that.  No need to use two font tags, though; combine those attributes (less text sent, more speed!).  I'm not sure of the SEO implications of going back to 4.01/Transitional, but I feel ya on speed.

Comment: Very cool - tested and and works beautifully. Thanks for your help Kevin and Mohammad. I will want to convert all the code to the XHTML at some point and get rid of all the redundant code. Then when it's polished and perfect, remove all white space. No images either - just speed, speed, speed.